# Using a C++ header with .NET language

Tags: .net, c++, com, interop, windows-media-player

I trying to use a "`.h`" file from Windows SDK in a .NET language (maybe C#), but without success. This header exposes some Windows Media player functionality through COM. If I use Win32 C++, I can use it with no problems, so I thought that I could use Managed C++ as a "Bridge" to expose it to C#.

The header file is the `subscriptionservices.h` that comes with Windows Media Player SDK 11 (part of Windows SDK 6).

Is that possible? How could I use that header file in a .NET Application?

Thanks,
Eduardo Cobuci

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is that possible? How could I use that header file in a .NET Application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PInvoke to Interop with Win32. If you are trying to use a COM object you should be able to add a reference to the project. Have you looked at [this article?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wmp_pinvoke.aspx)

More practically you need to understand the kind of work that you are doing. If you are going to be doing lots of pointer arithmetic then I would recommend managed c++. If not C#. Good luck.

Comment: Was about to write the COM thing, so +1 for you instead. The header file is definitely COM.

Comment: Yeah...COM interop is extremely useful since many microsoft API's are exposed as COM objects.

Comment: I wish OpenGL ES was COM - then it wouldn't be such a nightmare to use it from .NET ;) Well.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a particular snippet of code or types that you are looking to use from the header file, you can paste them into the PInvoke Interop Assistant and get the C# code generated for you.

http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120

Answer (score 0):

Try [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/). I don't think you can use the actual header, but you can reference functions in external unmanaged DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is possible. P/Invoke is your friend. Use this link to translate the headers.

[Platform Invoke Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a head start on the C++ path, if you go that way.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wmpinterop

Note that the WMP interface has some tricky interfaces to P/Invoke into. For me, it's easier just to write a C++ wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is simply you can use PInvoke, if it's complicated I would suggest using C++/CLI. This allows you to create a 'bridge' between the managed and the unmanaged world.